# By the Quran or the Prophet's words only, may Riba be produced?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, riba, revelation

By referencing only the Quran or the Prophets words ascribed by cross-accusation, is it permissible to produce Riba?

The assumed beneficiaries of Riba, the lenders, are of course condemned for consuming Riba, but are the borrowers also expected to be judged for producing Riba?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in OP, those who devour riba are clearly condemned; the Qur'an is very clear on this when it says "[…Allah has permitted trade and has forbidden *riba*…](http://quran.com/2/275)…".

The Qur'an also clearly tells the believers "[…do not cooperate in sin and aggression…](http://quran.com/5/2)"; when it is known that taking *riba* is a clear sin, then knowingly and willingly producing *riba* so that it *can* be sinfully taken is easily a form of "cooperation in sin".